# $pull request in mongo to delete element of an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a node and mongo app that allows user to register competition events and post subscriptions to those events.
Every sub belongs to an event as you can see in the below mongo file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/CompetitionEvent')

export const CompetitionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  event_id: String,
  compName: String,
  place: String,
  time: String,
  subscriptions: [],
  date: Date,
  cost: {
    currency: String,
    amount: Number,
  },
})

[...]
```

Now all my routes are working just fine, except the last one. I want to filter by eventID and then by sub id in order to target the right subscription I want to delete.
Then I used $pullto try to delete the subscription but it doesn't work, any one has an idea?
http file:

```
const express = require('express')

import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser'
// import { eventApplication } from './compositionRoot'
import { CompetitionModel } from './mongo'

export const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
// WORKS - find all events
app.get('/events', async (_req: any, res: any) => {
  const comp = await CompetitionModel.find()
  res.send(comp)
})

// WOKRS - find just one event
app.get('/events/:event_id', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const searchedComp = await CompetitionModel.find(req.params)
  res.send(searchedComp)
})

// WORKS - posts a new comp event
app.post('/new-comp', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const data = await new CompetitionModel(req.body).save()
  res.json(data)
})

// WORKS - posts a new subscription into a comp
app.put('/update/:event_id', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const subs = await CompetitionModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { event_id: req.params.event_id },
    { $push: { subscriptions: req.body } },
  )
  res.send(subs)
})

// WORKS - deletes a competition event
app.delete('/delete/:event_id', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const toDel = await CompetitionModel.deleteOne({
    event_id: req.params.event_id,
  })
  res.json(toDel)
})

// TO TEST - removesa subfrom an event
app.post('update/del-sub/:event_id/:id', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const subToDel = await CompetitionModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { event_id: req.params.event_id },
    { id: req.params.id },
    { $pull: [req.params.delete] },
  )
  res.send(subToDel)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine your two conditions in one filter, and pass your $pull-operation in an object as the second parameter:

```
await CompetitionModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { event_id: req.params.event_id },
    { $pull: { subscriptions: req.params.id  } })
```

Comment: So when doing this I actually don't have an error anymore, which is a huge improvement.
However, nothing happens and the sub is still there.
Could it be due to the HTTP request type I chose? To me it is a modification of a document so app.delete doesn't look like the good one but maybe I am mistaken?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the http request-method. The problem is that `req.params.delete` is undefined and will not match anything. I took another look at your code and it seems that `req.params.id` is the id of the subscription you want to remove - I've updated the answer, it should work now.